# magento 2 setIsDefaultBilling not working

Tags: magento2

I want to save customer address via external script and I want to make different default shipping address and default billing address. In this I can set default shipping address and not able to set default billing address for the second address.

Code:

```
public function SaveDefaultBillingAddress($customerId,$data){
     /*Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory*/
 
    $billingaddress = $this->dataAddressFactory->create();
    $billingaddress->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
    $billingaddress->setLastname($data['lastname']);
    $billingaddress->setTelephone($data['telephone']);
    $billingaddress->setStreet($data['street']);
    $billingaddress->setCity($data['city']);
    $billingaddress->setCountryId($data['country_id']);
    $billingaddress->setRegionId($data['region_id']);
    $billingaddress->setIsDefaultBilling(1);
    $billingaddress->setCustomerId($customerId);

    try
    {
        /*Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface*/
        
        $this->addressRepository->save($billingaddress);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        return __('Error in shipping/billing address.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried.

Comment: @ManashviBirla

I have added that code snippet

Comment: are you getting any error? as far as i can see, there is a missing single quote in $data[street']. It should be like $data['street']

Comment: @ManashviBirla

i did this typo mistake here not in my script.

Comment: might sound stupid, but did you setting this by a boolean value? as in `$billingAddress->setIsDefaultBilling(true)`?

Comment: @DianaBotean

Its not working